# Date comparison with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to find a user with a user that has a location that is newer or older than a certain date.

**Schema**

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    facebookId: String,
    googleId: String,
    token: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    friends: [userSchema],
    location: {
        type: {
            timestamp: Date,
            accuracy: Number,
            coordinates: {
                lat: Number,
                lng: Number
            }
        },
        default: null
    }
}, {
```

**Query**

```
userSchema.statics.findRecentUpdates = function (ids, minutesSinceLast, callback) {
    var recentDate = new Date().removeMinutes(minutesSinceLast);
    this.find(
        {'location.timestamp': {$lt: recentDate}},
        callback
    );
}
```

**Data**

```
db.users.find();
{ "__v" : 1, "_id" : ObjectId("53cecb60fe7d090000030328"), "email" : "JzLrmXy@givnZhE.com", "facebookId" : "9138129367", "firstName" : "Cornel", "friends" : [  ObjectId("53cecb4dfe7d090000030327") ], "lastName" : "GD", "location" : { "coordinates" : { "lat" : 18.040808, "lng" : 59.330557 }, "timestamp" : 1406061408964, "accuracy" : 1 }, "token" : "988bb52b-cc0c-492d-8c75-f1f7d882157d" }
{ "__v" : 20, "_id" : ObjectId("53cf668eff9ef40000f76ce5"), "email" : "CZteADE@WFdFFiQ.com", "facebookId" : "5762365752", "firstName" : "Yuan", "friends" : [ ], "lastName" : "vh", "location" : { "accuracy" : 3, "coordinates" : { "lat" : 59.356862, "lng" : 17.996661 }, "timestamp" : 1406101134199 }, "token" : "51278cb7-9e55-4cc5-b635-7cd289b2fa6a" }
{ "__v" : 21, "_id" : ObjectId("53cecb4dfe7d090000030327"), "email" : "s@gmail.com", "facebookId" : "7237853051", "firstName" : "M", "friends" : [  ObjectId("53cecb60fe7d090000030328") ], "lastName" : "H", "location" : { "accuracy" : 0, "coordinates" : { "lng" : 18.0246476, "lat" : 59.3827026 }, "timestamp" : 1413838822856 }, "token" : "5d870480-05c0-4a83-ae44-cfe39692d308" }
```

No matter what I set the date to I always get an empty result. Trying with `'location.accuracy'` and setting less or greater than an that works.

Comment: Somehow, writing down everything and reading through it makes you think in new ways about the problem. Maybe I can try to use this some how without posting first :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is in how I stored the dates. As we can see from the data above they are stored as milliseconds `1406101134199` and not as the ISODate format `ISODate("2014-10-20T21:50:23.196Z")`. This was due to the line `Date.now()` which does not return the current date object but milliseconds instead. Using `new Date()` fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

> Need to put removeMinutes after assigning the new Date();

**Query:**

```
userSchema.statics.findRecentUpdates = function (ids, minutesSinceLast, callback) {
    var recentDate = new Date();
    recentDate.removeMinutes(minutesSinceLast); // It will remove the minutes
    this.find(
        {'location.timestamp': {$lt: recentDate}},
        callback
    );
}
```